# Validating USA phone numbers

Tags: php, validation, phone-number

Okay, so my code does work.  But, I need to edit some of it.  For example, I want it to allow numbers 7 or 10 numbers in length.
The second part is that it is not validating my numbers with `-` or `()` in them, which it should.  I want it to be able to validate numbers with the parenthesis or hyphens, no letters.

```
<?php
$phoneNumbers = array("111-1111",
                      "(111) 111-1111",
                      "111-111-1111",
                      "111111",
                      "",
                      "aaa-aaaa");

foreach ($phoneNumbers as $phone) {
    $failures = 0;
    echo "<hr /><p>Checking &ldquo;$phone&rdquo;</p><hr />";

     // Check for 7 or 10 characters long
     if (strlen($phone) < 7) {
          ++$failures;
          echo "<p><small>Warning: &ldquo;$phone&rdquo; must be 7 or 10 characters</small></p>";
     }

     // Check for numbers
     if (!preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $phone)) {
          ++$failures;
          echo "<p><small>Warning: &ldquo;$phone&rdquo; contains non numeric characters</small></p>";
     }

     if ($failures == 0) 
          echo "<p>&ldquo;$phone&rdquo; is valid</p>";
     else
          echo "<p>&ldquo;$phone&rdquo; is not valid</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) Example: `$phoneNumber = str_replace(")","", $phoneNumber)` replaces ")" substring with "" empty string;

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a regular expression only solution. Something similar to:

```
//Phone Number (North America)
//Matches 3334445555, 333.444.5555, 333-444-5555, 333 444 5555, (333) 444 5555 and all     combinations thereof.
//Replaces all those with (333) 444-5555
preg_replace('\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})', '(\1) \2-\3', $text);

//Phone Number (North America)
//Matches 3334445555, 333.444.5555, 333-444-5555, 333 444 5555, (333) 444 5555 and all combinations thereof.
'\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}'
```

Comment: Well, that is for another assignment.  For this one, I must use the string manipulation function.

Comment: @Lobita If it's for homework, please add the [homework] tag to your questions in the future. I've added it to for you this time.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen Okay, sorry, I'm new to this.  Will do next time.

Comment: not entirely sure but are your regex's here escaped? This is not necessary in PHP *if* they are. Otherwise, the two regex matches don't infact match